# How to get OS information whether it be LINUX or WINDOWS?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm running "QUdpSocket::ShareAddress" on my QT application but ShareAddress is ignored by windows. So I'm trying to solve this problem by identifying OS at run time.
I heard a couple of information about window version indentifier but I couldn't see any solution to solve my problem. 
If there is any of advice, it would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
#include <QtGlobal>
...
#ifdef Q_OS_MAC
// mac
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
// linux
#endif

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
// win
#endif
```

See QtGlobal documentation for further information.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't always the most elegant solution, but it's definitely effective to use a preprocessor definition to check platform at compile time.

Example:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Isn't _WIN32 for QT but C++?

Comment: Yes,it is not Qt specific defines. You can get list of them at http://predef.sourceforge.net/preos.html

Comment: Yeah, there was. Thanks for your help.